# QGIS "Profile Tool" Plugin inaccurate reading

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, srtm, profile

I'm getting an inaccurate reading from QGIS "Profile Toll" plugin as you can see in the image below.
Not only is showing incorrectly which of these two peaks is the highest, but also the altitude reading as you can see in the image is not correct. This peak, which is the summit, is documented as having an elevation of 2918m, not 2869m. And the Profile Tool is actually showing a lower elevation than the other peak next to it.

Could this have something to do with the DEM file that I'm using? It seems like the bandwidth in this file is not enough (?). I got this file via the plugin SRTM Downloader...

Does anyone have an idea of what's causing this?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SRTM DEM has a ground resolution of 30 meters (1 arc-second), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission#Highest_Resolution_Global_Release and references.

So the elevation is "averaged" over a 30x30 meter square. Average in quotes because it is not a mathematical operation, but a physical result of the backscattering of the radar beam used. SRTM heights can be quite wrong in steep terrain. See for example [Agrawal et al., VALIDATING SRTM DEM WITH DIFFERENTIAL GPS MEASUREMENTS – A CASE STUDY WITH DIFFERENT TERRAINS](https://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVI/part4/WG-IV-4-3.pdf) .

> Table 3 shows the error statistics for the Chamoli (Hilly)
> region. It shows minimum error of –31.8m and maximum Error
> of 48.44m with mean error of 8.22m. The RMS error is 19.64m
> with a standard deviation of 18.61m

Note that this is a hilly region and not steep mountain slopes.

[Mukul et al.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038%2Fsrep41672) (Mukul, M., Srivastava, V., Jade, S. et al. Uncertainties in the Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) Heights: Insights from the Indian Himalaya and Peninsula. Sci Rep 7, 41672 (2017). https://doi.org/10.1038/srep41672) find

> The accuracy of the SRTM data in the Himalaya decreases with increase in elevation for all SRTM Digital Terrain Elevation Data. Consequently, we find that the SRTM heights in the Himalayan foreland are most accurate followed by the foothills. The Higher Himalaya heights have the least accuracy.

So yes, what you see is the imperfect SRTM height model.

Maybe you can get a higher resolution DEM from somewhere?`

Also, how do you know that Google Maps places the peak at the exact, correct location? Maybe they also generated the peak markers from a postprocessing of a (different) DEM?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I suspected the problem had nothing to do with the plugin... Other than getting a higher resolution DEM (I have no idea where to get it) is there some alternative for doing what I'm trying to do? I'm trying to get the vertical cut of some mountains, something that shows a mountain's profile, as in a silhouette.

Comment: And keep in mind that the SRTM elevations reference the WGS84 Earth Gravitational Model (EGM 96) geoid.  What is the vertical datum of the mountain peaks?  The difference between a WGS84 surface and an some local orthometric surface could account for the difference values.  https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/datums.html